# Impossible to use the data partition of the user in huawei

Tags: stock-android, bootloader, huawei, bootloader-lock

Today i have turned on my Huawei g play mini and a screen appeared saying that it's impossible to use the data partition of the user and three options:backup,reboot and wipe.I have tried everything but nothing.I have tried to install the update.app file from recovery but nothing.I have also tried to install the os through fastboot but during the flash It fails saying:permission denied.I can't unlock the bootloader cause i can't take the code needed from the phone cause i can't use the dialer...I can use adb.I don't know what ti do...Can you help me?

Comment: To me it sounds like corrupted partition.

Comment: Yes,of course.My question is how to fix the problem:):)

Comment: Well I think that is impossible